# Chaining tasks using generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create an API for chaining tasks.

First, I designed a very simple interface defining a task:

```
public interface Task<U, V> {  
    U execute(V input);  
}
```

Where `V` is the input type and `U` the output type of the task.

What I whish to create is a `Chain` class that would chain a list of `Tasks`.

For instance, I would like to execute: `Task1<TypeA, TypeB> -> Task2<TypeB, TypeC> -> Task3<TypeC, TypeD>`

This `Chain` class would thus be a `Task<TypeA, TypeD>`.

So I wrote this code, which does not compile :

```
public class Chain<U, V> implements Task<U, V> {  
    List<Task<?, ?>> taskList;

    public Chain() {  
        taskList = new LinkedList<Task<?, ?>>();  
    }

    @Override  
    public U execute(V input) {  
        V currentInput = input;  
        U output = null;  
        for (Task<?, ?> task : taskList) {  
            output = task.execute(currentInput);
            // Compile error because currentInput is of type V
            // and output of type U  
            currentInput = output; // Compile error as well  
        }  
        return output;  
    }

    // Other methods to add and remove tasks in the list  
}
```

I do understand why it cannot compile but I have no idea how I could implement something that works and answers my problem.

Has anyone ever faced this kind of problem?

Kind regards,

Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Task` class is pretty much the same as the [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) class [`Function`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Function.html). You could use that instead of defining your own one.

An advantage of using `Function` would be that you could use the helper methods in the [`Functions`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Functions.html) class, one of which is [`compose()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Functions.html#compose(com.google.common.base.Function,%20com.google.common.base.Function)):

```
Function<String,MyObject1> stringToMyObject1 = ...;
Function<MyObject1, AnotherObject> myObject1ToAnotherObject = ...;
Function<String,AnotherObject> stringtoAnotherObject = Functions.compose(myObject1ToAnotherObject, stringToMyObject1);
```

Deeper chaining can be achieved by repeated calls to `compose()`.

Even if you don't want to use Guava for some reason, you can take inspiration from this approach: chaining any two functions/task with known type arguments creates a new function/task with easily-calculated type arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to maintain the tasks in a (nongeneric) list, you could try the "decorator" approach (for lack of better word), i.e. define a class which takes another task as a parameter, executes some task then passes its result to the other task. Or as a composite, which takes two tasks, and passes the output of the first as input to the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  The problem you have is that your output cannot be V and U at the same time.

```
public U execute(V input) {
    Object object = input;
    for (Task task : taskList) 
        object = task.execute(object);
    return (U) object;
}
```

Comment: This method is tempting (even though I would face potential ClassCastExceptions at run time).
What is odd is that is does not compile anymore if I replace the `Task` class in the `for` loop by `Task<?,?>` @peter-lawrey

Comment: Not odd at all, `?` means the compiler doesn't know the type cannot accept as an argument any type, since it doesn't know what it is.  As a return type `?` can only be cast to Object since `?` is equivilent to `? extends Object`